# Can I do a change of variable $x^n\rightarrow t$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that $\forall x \in [0,1]$
$$1-x^n\le\sqrt[3]{1-x^n}\le1-\frac{x^n}{3} $$

So I thought about changing $x^n$ to $t$ then calculating the derivative and using the mean value inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking if you can do that, or whether it would be a good idea to do that?

Sure you can do that.  If you can prove $1  -t \le \sqrt {1 - t} \le 1 -\frac t3$ for all $t$ where there exists an $\sqrt[3] t \in [0,1]$ then ... you are done.

But will it work?  That's for you to try.  I imagine it will.

But there are easier ways.  For $0 \le a \le 1$ we have $0\le a^k \le a$ and $0 \le a \le \sqrt[k] a \le 1$.  So if $x \in [0,1]$, $x^n \in [0,1]$ and $1-x^n \in [0,1]$ and $1-x^n \le \sqrt[3]{1-x^n}$ is immediate.

If we note that $1\ge (1 - \frac {x^n}3)^3 = 1- x^n +\frac {x^{2n}}3 - \frac {x^{3n}}{27}\ge 1 - x^n + \frac {x^{2n}}3 - \frac {x^{2n}}{27} = 1 - x^n + \frac {8x^{2n}}{27} \ge 1 - x^n$ we get $\sqrt[3]{1-{x^n}} \le 1-\frac {x^n} 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, proving the inequality for the variables changed in that way would be enough, since the mapping $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ is 1-to-1 on $[0,1]$.

Comment: What happens for $n<0$?

Comment: Sorry n is a natural number and $n \gt 0$

Comment: $n<0$ is a different story, of course. But I guess it is usually agreed upon, that $n$ is a natural number, unless stated otherwise. ;-)

Comment: @MarsPlastic Were you a Fortran programmer?  Though in Fortran $N$ is INTEGER by default rather than NATURAL.  C does not have that convention but does have a natural type (called unsigned integer).

Answer (score 1):

We have that$$1-x^n\le\sqrt[3]{1-x^n}\iff (1-x^n)^3\le 1-x^n$$ since $x\to x^3$ is increasing. Now, $$0\le 1-x^n\le 1\implies (1-x^n)^3\le 1-x^n$$ and you are done.

On the other hand

$$\sqrt[3]{1-x^n}\le1-\frac{x^n}{3}\iff 1-x^n\le \left(1-\frac{x^n}{3}\right)^3$$ since $x\to x^3$ is increasing. So, we need to show that

$$1-3x^n+3x^{2n}-x^{3n}\le 1-x^n.$$ That is

$$-3x^n+3x^{2n}-x^{3n}\le -x^n.$$ Or

$$3x^{2n}-x^{3n}\le 2 x^n.$$ Since $x^n\ge 0$ it is

$$3x^{n}-x^{2n}\le 2.$$

Now note that $x\in [0,1]\implies x^n\in [0,1].$ And the maximum of $f(t)=3t-t^2$ is just $2.$ So, you are done.

Comment: What happens for $n<0$?